# How do I make Cargo show what files are causing a rebuild?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, pyo3

I am using `cargo`, `maturin` and `pytest` to build a mixed Python/Rust project.  During development, I frequently cycle through the commands:

```
$ cargo test -p mypkg --release
$ maturin develop --release
$ python -m pytest --failed-first my_pkg
```

It seemed like cargo and maturin were compiling dependencies when there was not a reason to do so.  After some experimentation, I found that if I run

- `cargo ...`
- `maturin ...`
- `cargo ...`
- `maturin ...`

the second run of `cargo` and `maturin` would recompile the dependencies, even though I had not manually changed any of the source files.

I don't have a small example to reproduce this, so I am trying to debug it with the full system.  To do that, I would like to know what files cargo and/or maturin think are out of date.  Once I know that, the full solution will probably be obvious.

However, there don't seem to be flags that I can pass that give me that information.  `cargo -vv test ...` produces a lot of output about what it is compiling and how, but not why.  `maturin` does not even seem to have a `-v` flag available.

I found `cargo-outdated`, but that appears to be about dependency versions.

I have two Rust packages, each with 5-10 direct dependencies and about 100 total dependencies.

How can I figure out what files are causing `cargo`/`maturin` to rebuild the dependencies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can ask Cargo to output logging information relevant to *fingerprints*. With Cargo 1.56.0, the appropriate environment variable is `CARGO_LOG=cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint=info`.

As an example:

```
% CARGO_LOG=cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint=info cargo build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s

% touch src/main.rs
% CARGO_LOG=cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint=info cargo build
[2021-11-30T18:13:54Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint] stale: changed "/private/tmp/xxx/src/main.rs"
[2021-11-30T18:13:54Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint]           (vs) "/private/tmp/xxx/target/debug/.fingerprint/xxx-3af563e7d679143a/dep-bin-xxx"
[2021-11-30T18:13:54Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint]                FileTime { seconds: 1638295984, nanos: 344057437 } != FileTime { seconds: 1638296033, nanos: 750100000 }
[2021-11-30T18:13:54Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint] fingerprint error for xxx v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/xxx)/Build/TargetInner { name: "xxx", doc: true, ..: with_path("/private/tmp/xxx/src/main.rs", Edition2021) }
[2021-11-30T18:13:54Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint]     err: current filesystem status shows we're outdated
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution to my specific problem for the next user.

The [`CARGO_LOG` environment variable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174212/155423) worked.  It produced a lot of output along the lines of

```
[2021-11-30T18:29:06Z INFO  cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint]     err: RUSTFLAGS has changed: previously [], now ["-C", "link-arg=-undefined", "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup"]
```

I am pretty sure that `maturin` adds those flags when building a library to be imported by python.

At one point, I saw a way to modify `Cargo.toml` to add those when building with `cargo` as well.

My solution was simpler:  I ran the `cargo` tests with

```
cargo test -p mypkg # no --release
```

so that `cargo` builds and tests debug code and `maturin`/`pytest` builds and tests release code.  The flags are inconsistent, but not in a way that matters.  And if `maturin` changes the flags that it adds, I don't need to update my flags.

This does mean that when dependencies change, I build them twice, but that is much better than building them twice on every cycle.