# When does cargo build rebuild a crate?

Tags: rust, continuous-integration, rust-cargo

I have a workspace project with multiple crates in it. If I run `cargo test --workspace` twice in a row locally, it will only compile the crates the first time. But if I push a build to CI, and then push another build with just a dummy change to the README, it will rebuild the crates.

I'm using the following github actions ci config, i.e. it's doing caching:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@stable
- uses: Leafwing-Studios/cargo-cache@v1
- name: Run tests
  run: cargo test --workspace --release
```

I'm guessing that `cargo build` checks the timestamp of the files in the `src` directories, and since it's git cloning them out each time they're always "new", but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174147/how-do-i-make-cargo-show-what-files-are-causing-a-rebuild

Comment: Your CI might be using a container-based build in which case *any* source file change results in a complete rebuild, as one of the dependent layers has changed. Your local `cargo test` can finesse this better by checking individual files and their timestamps, etc.

Comment: Hm yeah I tried the `CARGO_LOG=cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint=info`, seems like it always thinks the files are updated because the timestamps are new, which I assume is because it's just been cloned in. I've posted an issue in the cargo repo: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11706